# Error on validation Django models relations from different applications

Tags: python, django-models

I'm trying to use relation between 3 models, from 2 different applications. When I try to validate models in the Django, got the following error:

```
CommandError: One or more models did not validate:
tournaments.tournament: 'city' has a relation with model City, which has either not been installed or is abstract.
tournaments.tournament: 'sport' has a relation with model Sport, which has either not been installed or is abstract.
```

I've installed all apps from project and **django.contrib.sites** on settings as seen here.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'location',
    'sport',
    'team',
    'tournament',
)
```

Tried to change order of apps on list too.

This is the **location** application's model.

```
from django.db import models


class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Country', max_length=200, unique=True)
    abbr = models.CharField('Abbreviation', max_length=6, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        app_label = 'location'
        verbose_name_plural = 'countries'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class State(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey('Country', verbose_name=u'country')
    name = models.CharField('State', max_length=200, unique=True)
    abbr = models.CharField('Abbreviation', max_length=6, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('country', 'name')
        unique_together = ('name', 'country')
        app_label = 'location'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class City(models.Model):
    state = models.ForeignKey('State', verbose_name=u'state')
    name = models.CharField('City', max_length=200, unique=True)
    abbr = models.CharField('Abbreviation', max_length=6, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('state', 'name')
        unique_together = ('name', 'state')
        app_label = 'location'
        verbose_name_plural = 'cities'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

This is the **sport** application's model

```
from django.db import models


class Sport(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField('Sport', max_length=200, unique=True)
    abbr = models.CharField('Abbreviation', max_length=6, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        app_label = 'sport'
        db_table = 'sports'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

And finally **tournament** application's model

```
from django.db import models
from location.models import City
from sport.models import Sport


class Tournament(models.Model):

    territory = (
        (1, u'International'),
        (2, u'National'),
        (3, u'Regional'),
    )

    name = models.CharField('Tournament', max_length=200, unique=True)
    abbr = models.CharField('Abbreviation', max_length=6, unique=True)
    city = models.ForeignKey('City', verbose_name=u'city')
    sport = models.ForeignKey('Sport', verbose_name=u'sport')
    regional = models.PositiveIntegerField(u'Status', default=1, choices=territory)
    start = models.DateTimeField('Start Date')
    end = models.DateField('End Date')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        unique_together = ('name', 'city', 'regional')
        app_label = 'tournament'
```

I've read a lot os posts here and out, as well Django's project documentation, but I can't find what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, have you done `python manage.py syncdb` and/or run the South migration on all the apps?

Have you tried changing these lines

```
city = models.ForeignKey('City', verbose_name=u'city')
sport = models.ForeignKey('Sport', verbose_name=u'sport')
```

to this?

```
city = models.ForeignKey('location.City', verbose_name=u'city')
sport = models.ForeignKey('location.Sport', verbose_name=u'sport')
```

Comment: Thanks, worked flawlessly. Anyway, I've tried to run syncdb, but failed too. Don't had tried South too.